# How to concatenate arrays in bash?

Tags: arrays, bash, shell, concatenation

How can I read lines from the standard input into an array and then concatenate the array with itself?

My code is:

```
countries=()
while read -r country; do
    countries+=( "$country" )
done
countries=countries+countries+countries # this is the wrong way, i want to know the right way to do it
echo "${countries[@]}"
```

Note that, I can print it thrice like the code below, but it is not my motto. I have to concatenate them in the array.

```
countries=()
while read -r country; do
    countries+=( "$country" )
done
echo "${countries[@]} ${countries[@]} ${countries[@]}"
```

Comment: you have appended array in your own code...

Comment: @HuStmpHrrr, appending individual items to an array (via appending a single-value array), yes, but I can grok how someone wouldn't understand what the syntax they're already using does.

Comment: But I did not know, how to add itself. Thanks. @HuStmpHrrr

Comment: @Mehdi Charife, I'm not sure I'd describe sample input and actual/intended output "unnecessary content". In the [mre] definition, they're both things we explicitly ask be included.

Comment: Yes; making the OP's goal crystal clear is exactly the point; in this case, a MRE just demonstrates that there's nothing surprising/unusual that wasn't covered in the English-language description, but even so it's useful: often we have folks who _do_ leave things out of their prose descriptions.

Answer (score 87, accepted):

First, to read your list into an array, one entry per line:

```
readarray -t countries
```

...or, with older versions of bash:

```
# same, but compatible with bash 3.x; || is to avoid non-zero exit status.
IFS=$'\n' read -r -d '' countries || (( ${#countries[@]} ))
```

---

Second, to duplicate the entries, either expand the array to itself three times:

```
countries=( "${countries[@]}" "${countries[@]}" "${countries[@]}" )
```

...or use the modern syntax for performing an append:

```
countries+=( "${countries[@]}" "${countries[@]}" )
```

Comment: When concatenating arrays like in the last example, why does it not use `"${countries[*]}"` (instead of `"${countries[@]}"` like when printing)?

Comment: @jww, using `"${countries[*]}"` would be adding only *one* array element containing a string with the entire list of countries concatenated together, as opposed to one element per country.

Comment: @jww, ...whereas by contrast, `${countries[*]}` without the quotes would be changing countries with spaces in their names -- `New Guinea`, say -- to separate each word into its own list element (adding a separate array element for each of `New` and `Guinea`).

Answer (score 21):

Simply write this:

```
countries=$(cat)
countries+=( "${countries[@]}" "${countries[@]}" )
echo ${countries[@]}
```

The first line is to take input array, second to concatenate and last to print the array.

Comment: `countries=$(cat)` is assigning a single string, taken from stdin, to the first element of the array; the individual elements are not broken out into individual countries. (Use `declare -p countries` to display the array's definition, and the behavior will be obvious).

Comment: ...which is to say, your array is not `countries=( A B C A B C A B C )` but `countries=( "A B C" "A B C" "A B C" )` when you do this; it's simply not visible that this is a problem because the `echo` command in use is inadequately quoted and so splits its arguments. Use `printf '%q\n' "${countries[@]}"`, and each set will be on a different line, which will likewise make the issue visible (whereas if the array were correctly populated, each *country* would be on a different line).

Answer (score 1):

on ubuntu 14.04, the following would concatenate three elements (an element count would give :3), each element being an array `countries`:

```
countries=( "${countries[@]}" "${countries[@]}" "${countries[@]}" )
```

while the below would concatenate all elements in one single array:

```
countries=( ${countries[*]} ${countries[*]} ${countries[*]} )
```

a count of this would be 30 (taken into account the countries specified in the original post).

Comment: This is false. `countries=( "${countries[@]}" "${countries[@]}" "${countries[@]}" )` expands the original array three times, creating one element per original array element each of those three times. `countries=( ${countries[*]} ${countries[*]} ${countries[*]} )`, by contrast, _string-splits and glob-expands_ the original array. Let's say that you had `countries=( "New Guinea" "New Zealand" "North Korea" )`; `result=( "${countries[@]}" "${countries[@]}" "${countries[@]}" )` expands to nine items.

Comment: By contrast, `result=( ${countries[*]} ${countries[*]} ${countries[*]} )` expands to *eighteen* items, because each `New` becomes its own array element. (It's even more complicated if any of the words it splits into is a glob that can match files on the local disk!)

Comment: ...see this code run in an online interpreter, with its output, at https://ideone.com/Bj9LLM